# Blocking HTTPS content with a Watchguard (Websense) vs. SQUID and SQUIDGuard using Transparent Proxy mode

Tags: firewall, pfsense, content-filter

I'm trying to compare these 2 solutions when it comes to content blocking :

1 - A pFSense appliance with SQUID and SQUIDGUARD packages configured

2 - A Watchguard FW that uses Websense

So, in order to block something like https://www.facebook.com, using Squidguard aparently I have to perform a MITM attack , or give up on the option of using the Transparent Proxy mode, but the Watchguard manages to block the very same page without losing the Transparent proxy option. Can someone help me understand how does that work, please?

Comment: You have to do [exactly the same thing with Websense](http://www.websense.com/content/support/library/deployctr/v76/dic_wcg_deploy_issues.aspx#603172).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Watchguard has HTTPS full-content inspection in the same way by installing an SSL certificate and doing a Man-In-The-Middle (MITM) attack on all the traffic, but it can blocking domain names without resorting to that by looking at the Server Name Indicator field sent out by the browser so the server can identify which SSL certificate to answer with, and by looking at the SSL certificate returned from the server to see which domain names it's signed for.

> HTTPS-Proxy: Domain Names
>
> If your Firebox or XTM device runs Fireware XTM v11.9.4 or higher, you can configure your device to allow or deny access to a site, perform content inspection, or bypass content inspection based on the Domain Names rules you create. To match the specified pattern in your Domain Names rules against the name specified in the connection server, the SNI (Server Name Indication), the certificate common name (CN), or the IP address of the server is used.
>
> Because it can determine the actual server name from the HTTPS traffic headers, the SNI is the most accurate option. A certificate CN is often shared between several services from the same site. For example, many Google services such as YouTube and Google Maps share the same certificate CN. If you block access to YouTube based on the certificate CN, access is also blocked to Google Maps and other services with the same CN. The certificate CN is used if the SNI is not available.
>
> http://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/wsm/xtm_11/en-US/index.html#en-US/proxies/https/https_domain_names_c.html%3FTocPath%3DProxy%2520Settings%7CAbout%2520the%2520HTTPS-Proxy%7C_____3